# AWS Network ACL - How to bulk upload blacklisted ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a list of around 100 IPs which I need to block through Network ACL to prevent connection to EC2 instance on ssh port. Instead of adding each IP one by one,  I am looking to copy paste or upload as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a soft limit of 20 rules (inbound and outbound combined) and a hard limit of 40 rules per NACL, which would be a show-stopper in your case (as your requirement is to have 100 IPs, unless those could be combined within a range)
Thus I would recommend you to look for other options (rely only on Security Groups that are allowing ash access only from certain IPs) or look into [AWS Network Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-network-firewall-new-managed-firewall-service-in-vpc/).

To directly answer your question, there is no way for bulk upload of NACL rules in the AWS console, but it should be possible to loop over a list of IPs with an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) of your preference.